# Is there a word for identifying oneself with a brand?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The title seems clear to me but I'll add an example:
There are several different apps for Telegram (Android, iOS, PC, etc) that all have the name Telegram and use similar Logos, designs and have a similar general appearance, making them "identify with" the telegram brand.
Is there a word for such behaviour in the english language or should I use "identify with"?
If yes is there a distinction between the subject being alive (a salesperson) or being not-alive (an app or a car)?

Example sentence: "George uses the app that is _______ for Telegram."

I am **not** talking about piracy but rather about a company enforcing/having certain style guidelines.

Comment: @Keepthesemind that seems to be what I was searching for, thanks. Is there a verb for such behaviour?
Yes, I was talking about entities belonging to the company/brand, not customers.

Comment: RE: _I don't know how build a sentence with a word that I don't know._ You use a blank to do that. For example: "George uses the Telegram app that is _______ for iOS." (I don't know if that's a good sentence – you'll have to figure out a good one.) Good thing you're allowed to edit your question after it's been submitted.

Comment: Do you want to imply an unlawful infringement on trade dress, or something just short of that? Counterfeiting is unlawful. Infringing on trade dress is unlawful.

Comment: @J.R. thanks, originally I was referring to there being more than 1 way to use a verb in a sentence and afaik some verbs only being used in certain ways.

Comment: @PhilSweet no infringement, no counterfeit, just a part of the company broadcasting the fact that it is part of that company/brand by style choices.

Comment: @MaxMatti Then try [trade dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_dress) and see if that covers it.

Comment: It only just occurred to me that the OP probably means "identifying oneself to others using ones own brand" If the OP agrees, we can hang a clearer title on the post.

Comment: @PhilSweet I was talking about entities within one company, there are no third-party-interactions in my example. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To brand**

> (Marketing) to give a product a distinctive identity by means of characteristic design, packaging, etc

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brand

Answer (score 1):

Affiliated? I think that might be the word your looking for.

- officially attached or connected to an organization.

Answer (score 0):

**Trade dress**

> To gain registration in the Principal Register or common law
>   protection under the Lanham Act, a trade dress must be “distinctive.”
>   This means that consumers perceive a particular trade dress as
>   identifying a source of a product.[20]

[Trade dress wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_dress)

Trade dress is a legal term and is a form of intellectual property that can be legally defended in court. Trade dress can be licenced down stream or be a condition of supply contracts.